# Movendo arquivos em pastas

Tags: arquivo, python-2.7

Possuo uma pasta chamada **teste**.

Dentro dessa pasta existem 1000 subpastas numeras de 1 à 1000.

Dentro de cada uma dessas subpastas existe uma outra pasta chamada **reports**

Dentro de cada pasta **reports** existe um arquivo chamado **report.json**

Preciso pegar cada um desses arquivos **report.json** e move-los para a pasta **destino**.

Possuo o seguinte script:

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

source = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\teste\\**numero_da_pasta**\\reports\\"
dest1 = dst = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\destino\\"

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if f == "report.json":
        shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
```

Ele é capaz de mover o arquivo report.json para a pasta destino, porém toda vez tenho que, manualmente, modificar o número_da_pasta para 2, 3, 4 etc...

Como faço para esse processo ficar todo automatizado? Não estou conseguindo fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra trocar o nome de pasta basta utilizar a seguinte função:

```
os.rename(old, new)
```

pelo que entendi voce deseja numerar a pasta destino, correto?

Nesse seu caso seria algo como:

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

source = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\teste\\**numero_da_pasta**\\reports\\"
dest1 = dst = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\destino\\"

files = os.listdir(source)
i = 1
for f in files:
    if f == "report.json":
        shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
    os.rename(dest1 + "destino", dest1 + "destino" + str(i))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Obrigado @Clayton Tosatti acho que não consegui explicar bem o meu problema, mas com a lógica que você propôs eu consegui fazer funcionar.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: ótimo Danilo! Disponha ;)